# android how to link ccp program at runtime dynamicly with device library

Tags: android, c++, hyperlink, compilation

i am implemanting OpenCL on android 6. I am able to compile and link cpp code that use opencl. The problem is that i need to copy the library from the phonne device to jni to be able to compile and link my cpp program.

So i would like to know if it is possible to compile and link my cpp program at runtime (when the app run on phonne device). So the library which are needed for compilation dans link will be taken directly from the phonne device.

I do not know if libGLES_mali.so and libOpenCL.so are standart on device that can run opencl

sorry for my bad english.